# In R, how can I search for the character vector element that is contained in a specific string?

Tags: r, string, vector, string-matching

I have a character vector element in R akin to:

```
[1] Deer  giraffe  hippopotamus lion
```

and a string such as

```
a <- "ogiraffeps"
```

How can I find the index of the element in the character vector which has the pattern contained in my string? I want to be able to do this without looping through the character vector

I am new to R, but it seems that **grep** can't handle this as it always uses a single string (the pattern) to see if it is contained in a character vector. However, what I want to do is to find an element of the character vector that is contained in the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`stringr::str_detect` is vectorised over the pattern:

```
library(stringr)
u <- c("Deer", "giraffe", "hippopotamus", "lion")
a <- "ogiraffeps"

str_detect(a, u)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Thus you can do:

```
match(1, str_detect(a, u))
# [1] 2
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I make this case insensitive?

Comment: @ag14: `str_detect(a, regex(u, ignore_case = TRUE))`